# JBOSS 7.1.1 deploying CXF jars

Tags: cxf, jboss7.x

I am very new to application servers and have recently switched to JBOSS 7.1.1.

I understand this comes shipped with Apache CXF but the CXF jars are not initially deployed?

How do I deploy them. I thought I would have to insert the dependency into the MANIFEST.MF. But which MANIFEST, i.e which jar, using some research it looks like setting a dependency in one manifest means it can be picked up by other jars so does it matter where I put it?

Plus once I edit the MANIFEST will the appserver pick up the new dependency on restart and is there a way to tell if the CXF jars have indeed been deployed?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CXF jars(ie. Module in JBOSS 7.x terminology) are available to you by default on startup. You would not need to insert the dependency in MANIFEST.MF file. Let me know if you have any further questions.